# Magento2.1 Helper; what's the difference between "extend" and "use" of AbstractHelper

Tags: magento2, php, module, helper

In Magento 2 we have to create a lot of data for ourselves using helper-modules. In the `Vendor/Example/Helper/Data.php` I often see either of these two at the top of the file:

- `use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;`
- `class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper`

And sometimes both: 
`use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
class Data extends AbstractHelper`

And I'm wondering, is there any difference to either `use` or `extend` the AbstractHelper? Is there a right or wrong?

A simple answer I found is this:

> You can use multiple traits, you can't extend multiple classes.

Does this translate into you either `extend` to add new stuff to it, and `use` it to get existing data? And again, is there an upside or downside in using either in Magento?

Comment: The `use` keyword just allows you to reference that class without supplying the full namespace, thereby improving the readability of code. It's purely aesthetic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up the `use` operator.

Using the operator outside of a class definition or inside of a function allows you to import/alias namespaces, which are used for aesthetic purposes only. It also helps to keep the code more readable, because you get rid of unnecessary fully qualified names.

```
namespace Vendor\Module;

use My\Class;

class Foo
{
    public function Bar()
    {
        use My\Class2;

        $foo = new Class();
        $bar = new Class2();
    }
}
```

Using the operator inside the class definition allows you to add traits.

```
namespace Vendor\Module;

class Foo
{
    use My\Trait;

    public function Bar()
    {
        return $this->myTraitFuntion();
    }
}
```

Regarding your question when to use `extend` and `traits`:

`Extend` when you need to override methods, extend a more generic class or you want to extend core classes.

Use a `trait` when you have reusable methods like a simple logger method or a format method you want to use in multiple classes.

PS: Magento 2 has only less than 10 traits in its core.